# WSL 1 (legacy) to 2 migration

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have WSL (Linux subsystem on Windows 10) installed with ubuntu 21.04 (**not from the store, it's the first version that appeared on Windows 10**), how can I migrate to version 2 (with an actual kernel) while keeping all my files (system and user), if possible without reinstalling everything ?

EDIT `wsl -l -v` gives:

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Legacy          Running         1
  Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         2
```

Which is WSL 1. I would like to go to WSL 2.

Comment: You run `wsl --set-default-version 2`[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1556115/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-get-default-version#:~:text=at%204%3A13-,WSL%20allows%20you%20to%20set%20the%20default%20version%20used%20by,Windows%2010%20version%202004%20installed.) [Full Documentation Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual).  What part of the process are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound As mentioned, I'm not using the regular ubuntu distribution from the store, but the previous one (from before they appeared on the store), so it's not clear how to achieve what I want. I also updated the post.

Comment: It shouldn't matter.  Have you tried running `wsl --set-default-version 2` and then starting the instance?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but `uname -r` still gives "4.4.0-19041-Microsoft" (ie., WSL 1).

Comment: Provide the output of the command I gave you, then after that output, include the output of `wsl -l -v`.  If `wsl --set-default-version 2` does "nothing" then you have forgotten to install something. Just to confirm you are running 21H1+?

Comment: @Ramhound I still have "There is no distribution with the supplied name." and Legacy is still set to WSL1.

Comment: So you don't have an instance named `Ubuntu 2` you have an instance called `Ubuntu-20.04` which is already WLS2 by the way.  It is currently NOT running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131094/discussion-between-ramhound-and-soleil).

Comment: I suggest changing the title to **_WSL Legacy to 2 migration_**
(replacing "1" with "Legacy").
_Why?_
The fact that `wsl -l -v` says _Legacy_ is "version 1" is very
misleading. – It's not!
The response _should_ have said "version 0" or "version beta" or
something else that clarifies that *Legacy* is **pre** version 1. 
This also explains why [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685194)
got it all wrong.
Given the title _WSL 1 to 2 migration_, that answer is perfectly fine.
One has to know that _Legacy_ is a special case in order to understand
and answer your question correctly.

Comment: @Henke In the MSFT naming system, legacy is the name, 1 is the version (see my output of `wsl -l -v`).

Comment: By adding "legacy" to the title you are helping readers understand that it's a special case (unlike _normal_ version 1). 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible:

```
wsl --set-version Legacy 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The Legacy distribution does not support WSL 2.
```

For migration of files to another distribution, there are two possible ways.

1. First check if `wsl.exe --help` shows a `--export` options. If yes then export the installed distribution to a tar file. For example the command will be: `wsl.exe --export Legacy myfile.tar`. Then uninstall the Legacy distribution with `wsl.exe --unregister Legacy` command. And reinstall the distribution with `wsl.exe --import` command.
2. Or run the Legacy distribution and tarball the whole distribution, see this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins/1199498#1199498). Then uninstall Legacy distribution and reinstall it from that tarball.

From [github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4717#issuecomment-559194771) and thanks to [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

That’s super trivial, though reading the docs should come first.

```
$ wsl --help
…
    --set-version <Distro> <Version>
        Changes the version of the specified distribution.
```

So just do `wsl --set-version MyDistro 2`, wait a little, and that’s it.

Comment: Not that trivial, as I mentioned in EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

It might be required to fire up a PowerShell that is Run as Administrator
and enter:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

Reboot and enter:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2         (use the name of your distribution)
```

If you have any problems, please let us know.

You could also do the upgrade manually by
downloading and executing the WSL kernel latest package from
[WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi).

Before starting I suggest backing up the Linux distribution.
See the article
[Export and Import WSL Linux Distro in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/export-import-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/)
and also to create a Windows System Restore save.

Comment: From `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` I get "There is no distribution with the supplied name."

Comment: @Soleil - So run `wsl -l -v` and update your question so this answer can be updated.

Comment: @harrymc - You are on the correct track. I am exhausted so I can't submit my own answer. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4717) is the exact issue the author is facing.  [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3022) is where Microsoft suggests just removing and replacing. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting) is the correct link to the documentation the second GitHub issue links to. It should be as simple as, export, unregister, import.  The author should backup their home directory just in the event the export doesn't cover it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the info. I'm aware of the fact that export/import/tarball might be a solution, but there are also downsides. In any case, the poster used this in his own answer, so his problem is solved using your comment.